# Bulk Capture Multiple Transactions Simultaneously on Regular Paypal

Tags: paypal, capture

Does the PayPal backend have any way to check the boxes next to several transactions and capture the payments for them all simultaneously? Currently our accountant has to enter each and capture them individually, and it's somewhat time consuming.

It appears that you can ARCHIVE multiple transactions, but not authorize or capture them in batches.

Is there an extension or a feature to do this?

We're doing Payments with a business account and PayPal Express through Magento, if perhaps there's a way to do it through Magento I'd be willing to figure that out too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PayPal provides Batch capture feature at PayPal back end to capture multiple authorizations at once.
To capture a batch of authorized transactions:

- Log in to your PayPal account
- Click the *History* subtab, then *History* Page will appears
- Click the *Capture* button associated with any transaction
- The capture Fund page will appears
- Click the *Batch Capture* link that is located in the introductory paragraph
- On the next displayed page, Choose your date range or specific date and Click *Search*
- On displayed result page, Check the authorizations you want to capture, Review the capture transactions, make any desired changes and then submit them for processing

For more info, check below link:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture#batch-capture-multiple-authorizations

Comment: Thank you very much, our accountant simply hadn't noticed that paragraph, and I was afraid to hit the capture button, that worked beautifully.